# Puppet: Iterate over a hiera_hash in template

Tags: ruby, hash, puppet, erb, hiera

I have this in a yaml hiera file.

```
reg_connection:
  toronto:
    - host: apple.net
    - port: 701
    - user: george
    - ssl: true
    - allowed: banana,orange
  texas:
    - host: pink.net
    - port: 702
    - user: joel
    - ssl: false
    - allowed: blue,gree,red
```

I want to access the values of host, port, user, ssl and allowed for toronto and texas.

I have this in my manifest:

```
 $reg_connection= hiera_hash('reg_connection')
```

I have this in my template:

```
<% reg_connection.keys().sort.each do |location| -%>
<%= location %>host=<%= location[host] %>
<%= location %>port=<%= location[port] %>
<%= location %>username=<%= location[user] %>
<%= location %>ssl.enable=<%= location[ssl] %>
<%= location %>allowed.list=<%= location[allowed] %>
<% end -%>
```

I want this to output two blocks of configuration in my template: one for toronto and one for texas.

My puppet output shows that it doesn't have a value for host. How can i access that value?

Comment: Do note that the point of `hiera_hash()` is to perform a *hash-merge* lookup.  The data and results are necessarily hashes, but just because your value is expected to be a hash does not mean you need or want `hiera_hash()`.  The ordinary `hiera()` function will perform a standard priority lookup instead, and it will return a hash if that is in fact the type of the value it discovers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a number of problems. The first is that in this code:

```
<%= location[host] %>
```

...`host` is (correctly) interpreted as a local variable or method name. There's no variable or method named `host`, hence the error.

You want to access the value with the key named `"host"`, which is a string, so you must use that string.

```
<%= location["host"] %>
```

The second problem is in your YAML file.

```
reg_connection:
  toronto:
    - host: apple.net
    - port: 701
    - user: george
    - ssl: true
    - allowed: banana,orange
  texas:
    # ...
```

Here your have a mapping (which is like—and is parsed into—a Ruby Hash) with a single key, `reg_connection`. The value associated with that key is itself a mapping with two keys, `toronto` and `texas`. So far so good. But the value associated with `toronto` is a sequence (read: array), not a mapping, because each line starts with `-`. The mapping has five items, each of which has a single key and value. Another way to represent the same data structure is this, which may help to illustrate the problem;

```
{ reg_connection:
  { toronto:
    [ { host: apple.net },
      { port: 701 },
      { user: george },
      # ...
    ],
    texas:
      # ...
  }
}
```

What you want, I suspect, is for that innermost data structure to be a mapping, not a sequence:

```
reg_connection:
  toronto:
    host: apple.net
    port: 701
    user: george
    ssl: true
    allowed: banana,orange
  texas:
    # ...
```

The third problem is with the way you're trying to iterate over the resulting hashes:

```
<% reg_connection.keys().sort.each do |location| -%>
<%= location %>host=<%= location["host"] %>
<%= location %>port=<%= location["port"] %>
...
```

You've called `reg_connection.keys.sort.each` (note: in idiomatic Ruby, parentheses are omitted for empty argument lists), which means you're not iterating over the locations, you're iterating over the keys of the `reg_connection` hash. In other words, you're iterating over the array `["toronto", "texas"]`, so the subsequent line is equivalent to`"toronto"["host"]`, which isn't going to work.

You *could* replace `location["host"]` with `reg_connection[location]["host"]`, but that's overkill. Just do this:

```
<% reg_connection.sort.each do |location, values| -%>
<%= location %>host=<%= values["host"] %>
<%= location %>port=<%= values["port"] %>
...
```

There's no need to get `reg_connection`'s keys before calling `sort`—you can just call it directly on the hash. This will, in effect, convert the hash to an array of key-value pairs (two-element arrays), which Ruby has no trouble sorting. Then when we call `each` two values are passed to the block—`location` (they key, e.g. `"toronto"`) and `values` the hash with `"host"`, `"port"`, etc. keys.